# Need to stop Browser back for iframe loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, browser-cache, browser-history

I have a page which has an iframe and iframe has a quiz which loads up question bank. When i go till 3rd question if suppose and then try doing Back button the iframe loads with 2nd question in the iframe. Scores are affected as per previous state of the question.

I need to stop this loading of previous question in the iframe. The user is getting access to play again the question.

Codewise, i need to stop the browser back button and to prevent the action of back affecting the iframe loading the previous state.

I have tried some techniques of keeping the state using hash with question numbers but browser back is working independent of hash state changes but when the whole URL changes of the page then browser back is fired.

Also, i tried for incrementing a variable whenever the iframe gets loaded up, but on browser back as well the iframe is again loading up and i can't make out a difference of browser back in the above case.

Any ideas?

Comment: [How do I disable the "Back" button of a browser?](http://www.irt.org/script/311.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Best case would be for the question page inside the frame to automatically detect the question in progress and to always go to that question when the page loads.

If however the question page is not in your control, disabling the back button is rather tricky, because it responds different in each browser.

Browsers restrict overriding native buttons, because some developers will become malicious and create websites you cannot escape from by clicking back.

Comment: How to automatically detect the question change is next or previous which is purely dependent on Browser Back button...